# how to insert a javascript calendar in a form (PHP)

Tags: javascript, html

im new in php  but i need to do something

i have a form with 2 texboxs and 1 button

the first field will be filled with the name of the user and the 2nd field need to be filled with a date.

That information is going to be store in a mysql database

I want: when a person get to the 2nd textbox, it should popup the javascript calendar that i have in a folder, and when u select one date in the calendar.. it must fill the textbox2 with that date.

i dont know how.

i heard u can do it with   >insert onclick="".. but i tried to put the name of the calendar there  and it didn't worked

Comment: I would imagine that whatever javascript library/snippet you are using should already have this described.  Check the documentation.  At the very least include you current code including javascript in the question.

Comment: the js file has 150 lines..

Comment: Your question has 0 lines...

Comment: look.. i have a calendar made in javascript (http://pastebin.com/vKgq3Rde).. i downloaded it from a open source website... and i want it to popup when i click in the textbox2  in my php file..

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to jquery-ui's datepicker, that is exactly what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/
Alternatively a bootstrap (2.0) style one if your using bootstrap.

Comment: What do you mean by "website offline"?

Comment: the script says  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>..    that means its getting the source from a website.. i am right???  if thats true..  it cant be work without internet